# Linux's kernel list.h and MSVC

Tags: linux, list, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, kernel

Working on a cross platform project, I'm really interested to use linux kernel list.

Even though the implementation of Linux double-linked list (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h) does not involve too much code, I was wondering if it is safe to use it with a different compiler than GCC.

Especially, Can the list be used safely the MSVC compiler? Is there any part of the implementation that could fails using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation of double-linked list `struct list_head` is compiler-agnostic and will work with any C89-compatible compiler as [thread-unsafe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

With that interpretation macro `WRITE_ONCE` in `INIT_LIST_HEAD` implementation may be coded as simple assignment. (Originally, this macro uses *volatile*, which have no well-defined semantic in C standard for multithreaded programs).